# XPage widget updated workspace tab icon unexpectedly

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

When expanding an XPage widget from the side bar of the Notes client, the workspace tab icon of another application gets changed unexpectedly. Does anyone encounter similar issue and has a solution?

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Create a blank database named "test.nsf" on the Domino server.
2. Open test.nsf with Domino Designer client and then create a new Xpage named "test.xsp". Close the Domino Designer client.
3. Open test.nsf with Notes client, then right-click on the workspace icon of test.nsf and select: Application -> Properties -> "Launch" tab.
4. Set the "When opened in the Notes client" property as "Open designated XPage (Standard client)" and "XPage: test.xsp".
5. Double-click the workspace icon of test.nsf to launch the application.

   [image]
6. From the "Widgets" toolbar, select "Configure a Widget from Current Context...".
7. On the "Configure a widget from Notes" dialog box, select "Open this XPage", then click "Next".
8. On the "Configure a Widget" dialog box, choose the "Display as a panel" option, then click "Finish".
9. Close test.nsf from the Notes client.
10. From the side bar, select "My Widgets". You will see the icon of your newly created XPage widget.
11. From the side bar, click the title of your widget to expand the widget.
12. You will find that the workspace tab icon of the current application on the workspace has been changed to the database icon of test.nsf unexpectedly.

    [image]

Comment: What exact version of the Notes client? And it might be works as designed - since your widget now has the focus and thus projects the icon decorator on the current tab. You can check that by opening another tab before opening the widget - you might find Home un-altered

Comment: Hi stwissel, in my testing environment, both Notes client 9.0 and 9.0.1 have the mentioned behavior. However, Notes client 8.5.3 does not have that.

Comment: In fact, I’m wondering why an XPage widget on the side panel needs to project its icon decorator on the current tab, as the current tab can be something totally not related to the widget’s own database (e.g. that can be “Home” or any other opened databases). Users may feel odd when the they see the database icon on the current tab gets changed unexpectedly.

Comment: I think it is called "a bug" - file a PMR for it